# How to solve the differential equation $y''(1-y)=y'(1+y')$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

<sub>My first second order differential equation! :D</sub>

---

So I was bored, and decided to solve some differential equations for fun. After a while, I came up with this:$$y''(1-y)=y'(1+y')$$which I thought that I might be able to solve. Here is my attempt:

Letting$$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=u\implies\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\dfrac{du}{dx}=u\dfrac{dy}{dx}$$we have$$\dfrac{du}{dy}(1-y)=1+u\implies\dfrac{du}{1+u}=\dfrac{dy}{1-y}$$which implies that we have$$\ln|1+u|=-\ln|1-y|+\ln|A|$$where $A$ is some constant which implies that we have$$\ln|1+u|=\ln\left|\dfrac A{1-y}\right|\\\implies u=\dfrac{A-1+y}{1-y}=\dfrac{B+y}{1-y}$$which implies that we have$$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{B+y}{1-y}\\\implies\int\dfrac{1-y}{y+b}dy=\int dx\\\implies\ln|y+B|-\int\dfrac y{y+B}=x+c\\\implies\ln|y+B|-y+c+B\ln|y+B|=x+c$$So now we have$$(1+B)\ln|y+B|-y=x+c\\\implies(y+B)^{1+B}e^{-y}=e^{x+c}\\\implies(y+B)e^{-y/(1+B)}=e^{(x+c)/(1+B)}\\\implies(-y+B)e^{-y/(1+B)}=-e^{(x+c)/(1+B)}\\\implies\dfrac{(-y+B)e^{-y/(1+B)}}{1+B}=-\dfrac{-e^{(x+c)/(1+B)}}{1+B}\\\implies\dfrac{(B-y)e^{(B-y)/(1+B)}}{1+B}=\dfrac{-e^{(x-c)/(1+B)}}{1+B}\\\implies\dfrac{B-y}{1+B}=W\left(\dfrac{-e^{(x-c)/(1+B)}}{1+B}\right)$$which implies that our solution to the 2nd order differential equation is$$y(x)=B-(B+1)W\left(\dfrac{-e^{(x-c)/(1+B)}}{1+B}\right)\qquad B\ne-1$$although I am unsure if I did this correctly since this is my first second-order differential equation that I've ever done, so my question is if I did solve this correctly or what I would I do to get the correct answer.

Comment: If your solution is indeed correct, you can plug it back into the original equation to validate your work.

Comment: @Chickenmancer I am aware of this, but I'm unsure how to take the first & second derivative of the Lambert W function, especially since we have $-e^{x\cdot c_0}$ inside of the W function, so I'm unsure how to deal with that.

Comment: $y=c_{1}$ and $y=-x+c_{2}$ are also solutions.

Comment: You should perform polynomial division first, then if necessary partial fraction decomposition or the integration. $\frac{1-y}{y+B}=-1+\frac{1+B}{y+B}$. This should shorten the computation by a couple of formula lines.

Comment: After logarithmic integration you need to take the constant out of the exponent and unite it with the sign of the resolution of the absolute value. Otherwise you miss solutions. $-(y+B)e^{-y/(1+B)}=Ce^{x/(1+B)}$, then $-(y+B)e^{-(y+B)/(1+B)}=Ce^{(x-B)/(1+B)}$. NB., there is no switch from $(y+B)$ to $(-y+B)$, what you want is $-(y+B)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT**

\begin{align*}
y''(1 - y) = y'(1 + y') & \Longleftrightarrow y'' = y''y + (y')^{2} + y'\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow y'' = (y'y)' + y'\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow y' = y'y + y + k\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow y'(1 - y) = y + k\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow y' = \frac{y + k}{1 - y}
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?

Comment: and if I did the math right, it should come out as$$y(x)=k-(1+k)W\left(-\dfrac{e^{(c+k)/(1+k)}}{1+k}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

If you switch variables, the equation write
$$(y-1) x''(y)-x'(y)^2-x'(y)=0$$ Reduction of order
$$x'(y)=-\frac {(y-1)}{c_1+(y-1) }$$ $$  x(y)+c_2=-y+c_1 \log(1-y-c_1)$$ You are ready for Lambert function